# Will the payout for mining will always be the same?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-reward

Will the payout for mining always be 0.00000064 BTC?
Because that is what i just got.

Comment: 0.00000064 BTC is what you got for what? That's a reasonable amount to get now for a difficulty-1 share in a mining pool, but you need to specify that.

Comment: Hello Rafi and welcome to the StackExchange. Your question is very subjective - I am guessing you are asking about a reward per share at a mining pool. It's best to ask the pool's support directly about such inquiries.

Answer (score 2):

No. The payout is determined by the block reward divided by the difficulty. The [block reward halves](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/block-reward-halving-a-guide/) every 210,000 blocks and the [difficulty changes](http://bitcoindifficulty.com/) based on the total amount of mining.

As I write this, the block reward is 25 BTC and the difficulty is 37,392,766. Dividing gives .0000000668, which would be the pay per share at this moment for a pool that charged no fees and kept all transaction fees.

Comment: That's assuming the reward system is PPS

Comment: @Dr.Haribo What's assuming the reward system is PPS?

Answer (score 0):

No, The payout is determined by the difficulty.

You can see how the difficulty has changed over time at this website.

http://bitcoindifficulty.com